# is it possible to pause a node.js script, prompt a user for input, and then restart the script?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to figure out if its possible for a user running a node.js script from the shell to pause the script, enter some input like verbosity level and then have the script continue execution. Basically I want to change a variable name (verbosity) while the script is actually running. The only other idea I had was parse a config file every few seconds with `setInterval` and reload the execution parameters.

Comment: Change a variable *name* or a variable *value*?

Comment: variable value of verbosity as I see it.

Comment: The value of something like `var limit = 100`; or `var verbosity = 1`;

Comment: No, that would require a Turing machine.

Answer (score 1):

Use fs.watch() to detect config file changes http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_fswatcher

example

```
// Require the file system
fs = require("fs");
// Watch the sim directory
fs.watch("text.txt", { persistent: true }, function (event, fileName) {
  console.log("Event: " + event);
  console.log(fileName + "\n");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the user to write your variable name whenever you want showing a terminal question (like a prompt). [stdio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stdio) module helps you a lot doing this. For instance, when you need user input you can write the following:

```
var stdio = require('stdio');
stdio.question('What is your variable name?', function (err, varname) {
    console.log('Your var name now is "%s"', varname);
    // Do here whatever you want with varname
});
```

I hope this helps. I'm the `stdio` creator. :-)

[image: NPM]
<sub>(source: [nodei.co](https://nodei.co/npm/stdio.png))</sub>

Comment: +1 from me, because this package helps indeed. i used the function ask() to stop a running script, then continuing with the rest of it, after answering the question or just hitting "enter"